# getting the selected options value according to user change

Tags: javascript

I have this simple select menu and its options:

```
<select name="selectMenu" id="selectMenu">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

I want to get the value from the selected option automatically so I  tried this:

```
let selectMenu = document.getElementById("selectMenu");
let scoreLimit = selectMenu.options[selectMenu.selectedIndex].value;
```

and with `.text` instead of `.value` too, no difference.

and I tried `let scoreLimit = selectMenu.value;` right away too, no difference

The problem is if you reload the page and the selected option is 1, for example, the variable `scoreLimit` will always be 1 even if I select a different option afterward from the select menu. I want it to update its value automatically without reloading the page as I select different options, how can I do this? (pure JS only if possible)

Comment: you need to add the [change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) event on the `select` element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be best to use a function

`const getScoreLimit = () => document.getElementById("selectMenu").options[selectMenu.selectedIndex].value`

and call it when you need (just like normal function)

`getScoreLimit()`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function and pass that function as callback function of *change* event of the element like the following way:

```js
let selectMenu = document.getElementById("selectMenu");
function selectValue(el){
  let scoreLimit = el.options[el.selectedIndex].value;
  console.log(scoreLimit);
}
selectMenu.addEventListener('change', function(){selectValue(this)});
selectValue(selectMenu); // call this for the default value on page load
```

```html
<select name="selectMenu" id="selectMenu">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```